# How do I get this font from my default TeX installation?

Tags: fonts

I am looking at a PDF file written by someone and I am 90% sure that it was written in LaTeX. But his output is much better than mine. Can anyone tell me which package is this?

[image]

Comment: You can see the names of the fonts used in the pdf's properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is Concrete Roman with Euler math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{concmath}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\bfdefault}{m} % Concrete has no boldface

\begin{document}

\section{The Two-Phase Simplex Method}

The LP we solved in the previous lecture allowed us to find an
initial BPS very easily.

Consider the LP to
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\textnormal{minimize}\quad   && 6x_1+3x_2 \\
&\textnormal{subject to}\quad &&
  \begin{alignedat}[t]{2}
  & x_1+x_2  && \ge 1 \\
  & 2x_1-x_2 && \ge 1 \\
  & 3x_2     && \le 2 \\
  & x_1, x_2 && \ge 0
  \end{alignedat}
\end{alignat*}
We change from minimization to maximization blah blah.

\end{document}
```

[image]

You should realize that the font is not available in scalable format, only bitmap.

Answer (score 0):

I think that font is computer concrete. Found it luckily from the [font catalogue](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ccr/). Thanks guys!